# PostgreSQL `analyse` vs `analyze`

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
explain analyse select true;
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                     QUERY PLAN                                     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1) ║
║ Planning time: 0.073 ms                                                            ║
║ Execution time: 0.109 ms                                                           ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

explain analyze select true;
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                     QUERY PLAN                                     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1) ║
║ Planning time: 0.030 ms                                                            ║
║ Execution time: 0.036 ms                                                           ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Is it feature or documented function (analyse = analyze)?

Comment: Analyze is used in the US and Canada, while analyse in Britain and Australia. Probably made synonyms to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Andre I heared about "color" and "colour", "czar" and "caezar" and so on. Learning the foreign languages is a really interesting thing! Thank you!

Comment: That's ok, but why `analyze` is so much faster than `analyse`?!

Comment: @klin Probably it is because it is the second one? (sorry for inappropriate articles if any)

Comment: Hmmm, my server also prefers `analyze`. Don't worry, (the?) English articles is my nightmare.

Comment: @klin ["Don't worry"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU) - One of the greatest songs. Good luck :o)

Comment: I saw that about three years ago - It is not 9.5 specific I believe?..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned it's only to support British vs American English. There is no difference in functionality. Even the [source code](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/kwlist_8h_source.html) has a mention of British spelling.

There is also no difference in the timing. If you run those a million times you will not see any reasonable difference in times. Running them once may show some difference, but one is not actually faster than the other.

You can also check the [parser source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/parser/gram.y). Both get parsed into exactly the same:

```
analyze_keyword:
        ANALYZE                                 {}
        | ANALYSE /* British */                 {}
```